# Make cdk diff ignore stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I have 2 cdk stacks that I have created that I use to deploy my lambda function. One of the stacks is the CodePipeline stack that gets triggered by Github commits, builds tests and deploys by using the "CloudFormationDeployAction" in CodeDeploy. Because I'm deploying my lambda through CodePipelines, I don't want it to be deployed through the terminal.

But on the terminal when I execute "cdk diff" or "cdk deploy *" for the rest of my stack, cdk will try diff both the stacks and output potential changes with the Lambda stack, even though it's deployed already. And doing a "cdk deploy *" will make cdk try to deploy and fail (due to missing parameters that is supplied through CodePipelines).

Is there a way to make the terminal commands ignore this LambdaStack?

Comment: If you have different stacks, say one for creating your CI/CD (CodeBuild, etc) and one for creating your hosting (initializing lambda) you should be able to run `cdk deploy` without deploying code.  Additionally, you can inidicate which stack you want to update via a command line parameter: `cdk deploy BuildStack`

Comment: I've been deploying with specific stacks ever since I introduced the LambdaStack which depends on parameters passed from CodeBuild. But, everytime I make a change on a different stack and I want to inspect my changes with "cdk diff", the LambdaStack also prints its resources and clutters up my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

A way I use to achieve a similar result is by doing the following:

1. In package.json I added under scripts `"cdk-diff": "tsc && cdk diff YourStackYouWantToDiff"`
2. I run `npm run cdk-diff`

This will only execute the `cdk diff` on the stacks you specify, here being YourStackYouWantToDiff.

In case of declared dependencies between stacks such as `aStack.addDependency(bStack)`, the `cdk diff` is executed on both aStack and bStack.